# Adding and removing class from HTML elements in ES6 / ES7

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6

I have the following [code](https://codepen.io/Rahul_V7/pen/KRYvBj) in which I have some `HTML button` elements.

I want that whenever I `click` a button, class `selected` should **toggle** in that button.

Here is the code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const [...btns] = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
  
  for(let i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      if(this.className.split(' ').indexOf('selected') > -1) {
        this.className = this.className.split(' ').pop();
      } else {
        this.className = this.className.split(' ').push('selected').join(' ');
      }
      
      console.log(this.className);
    });
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 3px 7px;
  color: #FF4A3F;
  background: #E7E7E7;
  font: 500 16pt calibri;
  transform: scale(1, 0.95);
}
.selected {
  background: #353553;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button>Home</button>
<button>Admission</button>
<button>Results</button>
<button>Curriculum</button>
<button>Contact us</button>
```

---

But, when I ran the above code, I got the following error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.className.split(...).push(...).join is not a function

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: push function returns the index of the newly added element in array, not the array. and join is a function that works on arrays. That is why you are getting the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can greatly simplify the logic by using `classList.toggle` instead. You may also use `querySelectorAll` which you can `forEach` over directly:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    btn.classList.toggle('selected');
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 3px 7px;
  color: #FF4A3F;
  background: #E7E7E7;
  font: 500 16pt calibri;
  transform: scale(1, 0.95);
}
.selected {
  background: #353553;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button>Home</button>
<button>Admission</button>
<button>Results</button>
<button>Curriculum</button>
<button>Contact us</button>
```

The problem with your original code is that `push` does not return the array; it returns the *length* of the array instead, so it's not chainable (unfortunately). Same thing with `pop()`.

Tweaking your code so that it works, *assuming* that the last `className` will always be `selected`, would look like this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const [...btns] = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
  
  for(let i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      const classNameArr = this.className.split(' ');
      if(classNameArr.indexOf('selected') > -1) {
        classNameArr.pop();
        this.className = classNameArr.join(' ');
      } else {
        classNameArr.push('selected')
        this.className = classNameArr.join(' ');
      }
      console.log(this.className);
    });
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 3px 7px;
  color: #FF4A3F;
  background: #E7E7E7;
  font: 500 16pt calibri;
  transform: scale(1, 0.95);
}
.selected {
  background: #353553;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button>Home</button>
<button>Admission</button>
<button>Results</button>
<button>Curriculum</button>
<button>Contact us</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const [...btns] = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
  
  for(let i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
   this.classList.contains("selected")?this.classList.remove("selected"):this.classList.add("selected");
    });
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 3px 7px;
  color: #FF4A3F;
  background: #E7E7E7;
  font: 500 16pt calibri;
  transform: scale(1, 0.95);
}
.selected {
  background: #353553;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button>Home</button>
<button>Admission</button>
<button>Results</button>
<button>Curriculum</button>
<button>Contact us</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that `push` doesn’t return the new array, it returns the length of the new array. [MDN docs for `push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). Therefore when you get to the `join`, it’s trying to join a number, rather than the array as you are expecting.

Fortunately for this use case there’s a method which you can use directly - [`classList.toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

```
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        btn.classList.toggle('selected');
    });
});
```

Comment: The only problem is for `classList` is `IE`, whereas for `className`, there is full support !

Answer (score -2):

Have you thought about using jquery to do this, they have a remove and a removeclass method for this:

```
$("button").removeClass("selected");


$("button").addClass("selected");
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I prefer to use Vanilla javascript as long as it is possible

Comment: No worries, for some Vanilla is easier to read and for others not :)